# Copying a cell with certain cell color background

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, background-color

is there any code that allows me to copy several cells by the color of the cell background? So I have a recap sheet and the summary sheet containing detail of the data. I colorized the type of data in the same background color (light grey) and it placed it on the same entire column. But the type of data has some space between type 1 to type 2 because each type has a summary beside the column and I need those data to be copied in one straight arrangement without any space. For example, type 1 would be on cell B6 and type 2 on B13 and I need type 1, and type 2 in the recap sheet would be type 1 in B6 and type 2 in B7. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

NB: currently on excel 2010

Comment: Hi, I'm new at vba macro currently, sorry but I haven't try any code for now.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you have a worksheet named "summary" that looks something like the left image and you want to copy the data in column B to a new sheet that already exists named "recap" like the right image.
[image]

If that is the case, then following code should work for you:

```
Sub Macro1()
    'declare sheets
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet, RecapSheet As Worksheet
    Set SummarySheet = Sheets("summary") 'the sheet with the data
    Set RecapSheet = Sheets("recap") 'where you want to put the copied data
    
    'declare ranges
    Dim originalDestinationCell As Range, nextDestCell As Range
    Set originalDestinationCell = RecapSheet.Range("B6") 'the first cell the data will be copied to
    Set nextDestCell = originalDestinationCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    Dim firstGreyCell As Range: Set firstGreyCell = SummarySheet.Range("B6") 'the cell with the grey fill-color
    Dim rangeToSearchIn As Range: Set rangeToSearchIn = SummarySheet.Range("B2:B2000") 'the range that the data is in
    'note: a larger range will take more time
    
    'move cell values
    For Each c In rangeToSearchIn
        If IsEmpty(c) = False Then 'only copy if the cell is not blank
            If c.Interior.Color = firstGreyCell.Interior.Color Then 'if the interior color of cell 'c' is the same as 'firstGreyCell' then
                Set nextDestCell = RecapSheet.Cells(nextDestCell.Row + 1, originalDestinationCell.Column) 'move the next cell down one column and back to the original column
                nextDestCell.Value = c.Value 'copy the value to the recap sheet
                nextDestCell.Interior.Color = c.Interior.Color 'copy the cell color too
            Else
                'if the interior color is not the same as 'c'
                Set nextDestCell = nextDestCell.Offset(0, 1) 'move the nextDestCell to the right by 1
                nextDestCell.Value = c.Value 'copy its value
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

The code assumes that all grey cells have a value (even if its just a space). It skips over blanks cells and also copies all data under the grey cells in the summary sheet to the right of the grey cell in the recap sheet.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean! Thanks mate!
Another question I want to ask are:
1. Can I add some more sheets? From the code above it seems only for one sheet. If it is possible, which part should I change?
2. Can I change the interior color to the excel 56 color index?

Comment: 1. add the desired sheets to a new collection; encapsulate the for-each loop in another for-each loop. at the start of each iteration, update the SummarySheet variable with the next sheet in collection. 2. yes. u can change B6 to any color.

Comment: could you give me an example of adding some more sheets? I try to add some more but it won't recognize the new added sheet